# Can't get the propper Xpath to pass to Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, jupyter, scrape

I'm stuck with a selenium scrape using jupyter. I'm trying to get the "download page data" from the bottom right corner of this page: https://polkadot.subscan.io/account?role=all&page=1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4eaA.png)

Also, here's the html code:

Download page data

I've tried copying the xpath and full xpath from the Google Chrome "inspect" tab, but it doesn't work.

Here's the code I used, but feel free to suggest anything else.

```
#Initiating Webdriver
s=Service('CHROMEDRIVER LOCATION')
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=op)

link = "https://polkadot.subscan.io/account?role=all&page=1"

driver.get(link)

Ingresar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/main/div/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div")
```

Here's the error I get:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div data-v-24af4670="" class="label align-items-center">...</div> is not clickable at point (125, 721). Other element would receive the click: <div data-v-c018c6b4="" class="banner">...</div>
```

Either fixing my code, or getting a new one that works with jupyer and selenium

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
url = "https://polkadot.subscan.io/account?role=all&page=1"
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[text()='I accept']").click()
time.sleep(5)
download_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[text()='Download page data']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", download_btn)
download_btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick (and Correct) answer! 

Can you explain a expand a bit more on what does your answer does, and if you can, why mine doesnt?

again, thank you so much!

Comment: The first one, that element is at the bottom of the page, so you have to scroll to that element and do the actions. The second one can be because of cookie information also, so you have to accept the cookie information, then you have to continue with your operations.  If this answer works for you, mark this as the answer.